# Pandas - group by id and drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data.

```
userid itemid timestamp
  1       1      50
  1       2      50
  1       3      50
  1       4      60
  2       1      40
  2       2      50
```

I want to drop users who have duplicate timestamps.
In my example above, I want to drop userid=1  because he has viewed multiple items at timestamp=50. userid=2 should not be dropped since he has viewed items in different timestamps.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***option 1***
Use `duplicated`

```
dropid = df.loc[
    df.duplicated(subset=['userid', 'timestamp']),
    'userid'
].unique()
df[~df.userid.isin(dropid)]
```

***option 2***
Use `groupby` and `filter`

```
df.set_index(['userid', 'timestamp']).groupby(level=0).filter(
    lambda x: ~x.index.is_unique
).reset_index()
```